# Save DATA stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I try to extract/save a data stream (XML) from an IP camera.

`ffprobe` output:

```
 Input #0, rtsp, from
 'rtsp://172.30.10.227/axis-media/media.amp?event=on': Metadata: title
 : Media Presentation Duration: N/A, start: 0.120000, bitrate: N/A
 Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive),
 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc Stream #0:1:
 Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
 **Stream #0:2: Data: none** Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

How can I put it on file or console output? I need "Stream #0:2 Data".

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i URL -map 0:d -c copy -copy_unknown -f data data.bin
```

Comment: Hello, thx for your quick reply

Comment: Hello, thx for your quick reply I've tried it,  but it didn't work.    


The output file is empty....
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Comment: Show the full log.

Comment: Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://root:root@172.30.10.227/axis-media/media.amp?event=on&video=1':  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp    Stream #0:2: Data: noneFile 'lepke.xml' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, data, to 'lepke.xml':  Metadata:    title           : Media Presentation    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100

Comment: Stream #0:0: Data: none
Stream mapping:  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [rtsp @ 00000000001b6b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet [rtsp @ 00000000001b6b80] RTP: missed 154 packets
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x

Comment: If the data stream is sparse, you may have to save stream on disk as `.ts` and then run command on that.

Comment: Hi,
When I disable the video&audio stream i can catch the metadata stream. When I dump the packets I see the metadata XML but I get this error
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
how can I override it?

Comment: You can ignore that. Since you are dumpng a timeless data stream - those timestamp warnings are immaterial.

Comment: ffmpeg -i "rtsp://root:rootroot@172.30.10.227/axis-media/media.amp?event=on&video=0&audio=0" -map 0:0 -c copy -copy_unknown  -err_detect ignore_err -f data data.ts

how can I ignore errors, the err_detect ignore_err doesn't work.. :(
thx

Comment: That's an input decoding option so it comes before `-i`.

Comment: ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err   -i "rtsp://root:rootroot@172.30.10.227/axis-media/media.amp?event=on&video=0&audio=0" -map 0:0 -c copy  -f data data.xml  
Same result. if i use "h" (dump packet) i see the xmls...

Comment: Well, that option ignores decoding errors, not demuxing errors. Since you're copying the stream, there's no decoding step. Can you share the input URL on a public IP?

Comment: Sorry I can't, because it is an closed network. But I find a solution with Gstreamer and UDPsink. It is working. :)